# How to call (open) a new TableView by tapping a row of an existing(actual) tableview

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, model-view-controller

I have been trying to implement different methods to open a new window with a tableview when I tap in a row of another table view, but nothing works and all the results on the web are for iOS or Swift.
I'm working in objective-c, for desktop (OS X, el capitan) with xcode (7.2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Add a transparent NSButton on top of the NSTableCellView you're using.
2. Create a new NSWindowController subclass and add the second NSTableView inside it with its NSTableViewDelegate/DataSource.
3. Connect the IBAction to the overlay button in (1) and have it instantiate the window controller created in (2). Call `showWindow:nil` and `[controller.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:]` to display the window controller. Don't forget to create a strong reference to the controller.

Example:

```
- (IBAction)didPressOverlayButton:(id)sender {
    CustomWindowController *controller = [[CustomWindowController alloc] init];
    [controller showWindow:nil];
    [controller.window makeKeyAndOrderFront:nil];
    _newController = controller;
}
```